# Что я делаю не так в docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Вот мой docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  todolist.notification.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}todolistnotificationapi
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/TodoList.Notification.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8443:443"
    networks:
      - my-network



  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: Notifications
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres123
    ports:
      - "5440:5440"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

А вот мой connection string

```
 "Db": "Server=postgres;Port=5440;Database=Notifications;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres123;"
```

Но у меня появляется во такая ошибка

```
========== Запуск ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/TodoList.Notification.Api_1$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
24e56259de6b
docker exec -i -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT="50286" 24e56259de6b sh -c ""dotnet"  --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages  "/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/TodoList.Notification.Api.dll" | tee /dev/console"
Unhandled exception. Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 172.19.0.2:5440
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.TaskTimeoutAndCancellation.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 getTaskFunc, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|203_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at TodoList.Notification.Api.Extensions.MigratesExtensions.AutoMigrate(WebApplication app) in D:\TodoList\todolist-notification\src\TodoList.Notification.Api\Extensions\MigratesExtensions.cs:line 13
   at TodoList.Notification.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\TodoList\todolist-notification\src\TodoList.Notification.Api\Program.cs:line 31
   at TodoList.Notification.Api.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: Порт БД postgre по умолчанию **5432**, возможно проблема в этом

Comment: В контейнере `postgres` вы пробрасываете порт `5440`, а сервер БД работает на порту 5432. Поэтому ваше приложение получает отлуп при попытке соединиться.